# force haproxy to https

Tags: ssl, haproxy, offloading

I can't get haproxy to force https. It works with http and https. I want it to force port 443.  When I try to force it using .htaccess, it says "To many redirects"

Here is my haproxy.cfg:

```
global 
    log 127.0.0.1 local2 
    maxconn 2048 
    user haproxy 
    group haproxy 
    daemon 
    tune.ssl.default-dh-param 2048 

defaults 
    timeout server 86400000 
    timeout connect 86400000 
    timeout client 86400000 
    timeout queue 1000s 

listen premierdis 
    bind 192.168.1.200:80 
    bind 192.168.1.200:443 ssl crt /root/.ssl/website.com.pem ciphers TLSv1+HIGH:!SSLv2:RC4+MEDIUM:!aNULL:!eNULL:!3DES:@STRENGTH 
    mode http 
    rspirep ^Location:\ http://(.*):80(.*)  Location:\ https://\1:443\2   if  { ssl_fc } 
    stats enable 
    stats uri /haproxy?stats 
    stats realm STATS 
    stats auth user:pass 
    balance source 
    option http-server-close 
    timeout http-keep-alive 3000 
    reqidel ^X-Real-IP: 
    option forwardfor header X-Real-IP 
    reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ https 
    server srvg-webc-11 192.168.1.21:80 check 
    server srvg-webc-12 192.168.1.22:80 check 
    server srvg-webc-13 192.168.1.23:80 check
```

Answer (score 3):

If you split out your configuration into one section for HTTP and one section for HTTPS, then you can use [redirect scheme](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.5.html#4.2-redirect%20scheme) in the HTTP section to redirect the client to use HTTPS instead.

```
global 
    log 127.0.0.1 local2 
    maxconn 2048 
    user haproxy 
    group haproxy 
    daemon 
    tune.ssl.default-dh-param 2048 

defaults 
    timeout server 86400000 
    timeout connect 86400000 
    timeout client 86400000 
    timeout queue 1000s 

listen premierdis-http
    bind 192.168.1.200:80 
    mode http
    redirect scheme https if !{ ssl_fc }

listen premierdis
    bind 192.168.1.200:443 ssl crt /root/.ssl/website.com.pem ciphers TLSv1+HIGH:!SSLv2:RC4+MEDIUM:!aNULL:!eNULL:!3DES:@STRENGTH 
    mode http 
    stats enable 
    stats uri /haproxy?stats 
    stats realm STATS 
    stats auth user:pass 
    balance source 
    option http-server-close 
    timeout http-keep-alive 3000 
    reqidel ^X-Real-IP: 
    option forwardfor header X-Real-IP 
    reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ https 
    server srvg-webc-11 192.168.1.21:80 check 
    server srvg-webc-12 192.168.1.22:80 check 
    server srvg-webc-13 192.168.1.23:80 check
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thank you very much!  I knew I was missing something easy. Do you see any issues with my config file that I need to fix? Anything you'd do better?